# Android design patterns for REST calls with AsyncTask

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask, crud

I'm developing an app in which I pretend to invoke a REST service for typical CRUD operations. Since I want to separate the requests processing from the UI thread, I'm planning to use an AsyncTask to do the separate work. However, my question here is: how should I desing my AsyncTask(s) model? Should I use one AsyncTask for all CRUD operations (is this even feasible?), or use i.e. 4 AsyncTasks (create, delete, update, retrieve)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really up to you, and perhaps, the REST service which you are consuming.

Some things to consider:

1. Is the service general enough that it would be easy to do everything in a with a single `AsyncTask`?
2. Will your code be easier to read and understand if you do things with a single `AsyncTask`?  I would tend to think that it would be easier to read if you did one `AsyncTask` for each operation. (ie, CreateTask, UpdateTask...)
3. Will I get the reusability that I am after with my choice (whatever it is)?

Personally, I would create 4 distinct `AsyncTask`'s, and any reusable code I might put in a base class, but again, it is really up to you for what is going to work best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a ContentProvider instead of using AsyncTask.

According to this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/8M0RTFfO7-M%5B1-25%5D

on Android 4 AsyncTasks will be sequential.

So, for that reason alone your solution may be less than optimal.

But, ContentProvider just makes more sense for what you are trying to do, as what happens behind the CRUD calls the user doesn't care.  You may want to run this on a separate thread though, as being on the UI thread for too long is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the `Loader` framework, available with the compatibility library. I have a subclass of `AsyncTaskLoader` for each of the CRUD operations, and it works really well!

I guess if you prefer to avoid having lots of classes you could use the same task (i.e. the create and update could technically fit in the same task) - when you subclass your `AsyncTaskLoader` create a `setParameters(...)` method which you can call when you create the loader in `onCreateLoader()`.

It might help to read the above after you've reviewed the [Loader documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).